# Passing Single Element Array Inline

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and this I have encountered several functions that accept an array of given elements (e.g. `int[]`). However, there are cases where I just have one int to pass and I was wondering how to do this inline (e.g. without defining an array variable first).

For example, how to simplify this:

```
int[] pidArray = { mySinglePID };
am.getProcessMemoryInfo(pidArray); // This one accepts arrays only
```

To something like (made up, doesn't work this way):

```
am.getProcessMemoryInfo([mySinglePID]);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use Anonymous Array for your code:

```
am.getProcessMemoryInfo(new int[]{mySinglePID }); // This one accepts arrays only
```

**Anonymous Array:** In java it is perfectly legal to create an anonymous array using the following syntax.

```
new <type>[] { <list of values>};
```

Answer (score 7):

try

```
int[] pidArray = new int[]{ mySinglePID };
am.getProcessMemoryInfo(pidArray);
```

oneliner would be

```
am.getProcessMemoryInfo(new int[]{mySinglePID });
```

Comment: Figured it out exactly 30 seconds after I posted the question. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Actually, your first example is same as the one posted in OP. You don't need to use `new int[]` explicitly, when using in place initialization. What OP needs is the 2nd one.

Comment: @RohitJain yes you are right. but this would also work wouldn't it ??

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this: -

```
am.getProcessMemoryInfo(new int[]{ mySinglePID });
```

So, you don't need to declare your array variable here. Just pass an *unnamed* `array` object.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you want to do:

```java
am.getProcessMemoryInfo( new int[] { mySinglePID } );
```

you can skip `new int[]` only in declaration, if you break it, that syntax is not working

```java
// NOT WORKING EXAMPLE
int[] pidArray;
pidArray = { mySinglePID };
```